# NULL replaced with \N in R H2O dataframe

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to convert a column in H2O data frame to numeric.

```
input$col1 = as.numeric(input$col1)
```

col1 has 3 unique values in my dataset: 1, 0, NULL
During the above statement I get:

```
"DistributedException from server: 'For input string: \"\\N\"', caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"\\N\""
```

Can someone please help?
Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible code snippet, which shows an example of what your input for col1 looks and allows us to recreated this error?

Comment: "input" is H2O dataframe in R. col1 is a field with distinct values 0, 1, NULL. I am able to convert other fields to numeric using as.numeric. The issue arises only with this field. It's similar to https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3049  but the field is not numeric.

Comment: what version of h2o-3 are you using? is this what you had `x = c(0,1,NULL,NULL)
a = as.h2o(x)
as.numeric(a)`

Comment: just as a quick note, I was not able to reproduce your issue in the latest version of h2o using the code example I posted above. so you might want to try updating. thanks!

Comment: I am using h2o version 3.20.0.6.
And my data is coming from Hive table which we import into R.